# Can't register/login with new FB account

Tags: facebook, cocoalibspotify-2.0

In order to test the user registration in CocoaLibSpotify, I created a new Facebook account. 
After creating the account (and validating the email address), I tried to log in to my app (using CocoaLibSpotify) but got the following error: "General Permanent Error" (error code 10 from CLS).

What could be wrong?

*Notes:*

- I've triple-checked the login credentials and have logged in to the account on Facebook.
- Trying to log in to another account with invalid credentials gives me another error.
- Also, logging in to an account with valid credentials works just fine.
- I haven't logged in to the account using any other Spotify client (desktop, regular Spotify client etc)

**EDIT:** 
In order to move forward, I logged in to the account on desktop and accepted the Facebook stuff and played a track. After that, I tried logging in through CLS again but got the error: "Needs a premium account". Aren't users supposed to get a 48-hour free trial upon first mobile login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aren't users supposed to get a 48-hour free trial upon first mobile login?

From Spotify's own client, yes. libSpotify applications aren't eligible to create new users and trials at the moment.